# Passing a model.find as argument to be called causes Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have been using ExpressJS for some time now. I'm learning to use Mongoose with it.

In the callback of my queries: function( error, data ) {...} I have a lot of repeated code with handling the error. For this I have made a function checkedQuery which calls the query, handles it's error, then passes the data to a callback.

Note, some of the code below has been removed, simplified, commented out as it is irrelevant to the actual question.

```
function checkedQuery( queryFn, callback ) {
  queryFn( function( error, data ) {
    if ( error ) {
      // ServerErrorResponse(....); Handles sending out the proper json error response
      return;
    }
    callback( data );
  });
}
```

Elsewhere in my mongoose models I have defined a function which simply gets a list of all User names:

```
UserSchema.statics.getNames = function( callback ) {
  var User = mongoose.model('User');
  User.find({}, 'name', callback );
}
```

Using these two functions together I have no issue:

```
checkedQuery( User.getNames, function( userNames ) {
  // ... Handles the user names
  return;
}
```

The problem I have is when I try to pass the User.find straight function into checkedQuery:

```
checkedQuery( User.find, function( users ) {
  // ... Handles the users
  return;
}
```

Here, I am receiving an error from the mongoose module:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'discriminatorMapping' of undefined
    at find (/mypath/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:955:18)
```

Lastly, on the actual code, I would like to note that calling User.find with only a callback function IS valid and causes no error:
    User.find( function( error, users ) {
      //...Handle error AND user data
    }

I suspect there is something wrong with the scoping and arguments that is causing this, but I'm unsure. Any help is much appreciated!

Also, if there are any examples you can point me to which show a better pattern for creating error checked query functions and functionally passing around mongoose queries in general, I would love to have a proven alternative.

Comment: Pass `User.find.bind(User)` instead of just `User.find`.

Answer (score 1):

Converting @idbehold's comment to answer:

Pass `User.find.bind(User)` instead of just `User.find`.